# Grades for PhD admission, what grades (B.Sc or M.Sc) are of most importance in Europe (STEM)?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

My B.Sc GPA currently stands at 4.33/5.00 and my M.Sc is projected at 4.90/5.00.

I am kind of freaking out, because of my low B.Sc GPA. I have ran through walls to compensate for it with my M.Sc GPA but I am very unsure whether or not I will make the cut. I even have serious doubts if I am of right material to pursue a PhD because of my Bachelor's performance.

Does anyone have a good insight of where I stand competition-wise? I am pursuing a degree in engineering (physics) in Denmark.

I have the opportunity to re-take some of the exams in my B.Sc to obtain higher grades, but I don't think I will be able to rise it more than 4.50 tops (due to time-shortage and not risking to much of mental/physiological health). Should I do it, or focus on something else?

Comment: From my experience, grades - and especially B. Sc. grades - are of very low importance in PhD admissions. Unless they're really bad, I do not think they will be the deciding factor of whether you get in or not. Cannot say much for Danish institutions, though. Regardless, try to make a very good thesis on a trendy topic, and maybe get a scientific publication out of it in the process.

Comment: Just a note: if there is a good reason for the low GPA you could mention it in your motivation letter (e.g., if you were a working student, ill, changed major, ...) or skip mentioning the GPA if allowed. But I agree with @P.Shark that your MSc is far more important for your application.

Comment: Don't doubt your ability to do a PhD based on your BSc performance! The skills needed to succeed in the two are totally different.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I will put my effort in my thesis and remaining courses and not better my B.Sc grades.